# Is there a way to step through SQL code in debugging mode?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, rapidsql

I am not a SQL developer, but I have a bit of SQL that is longer and more complex than my usual query/update. It is not a stored proc (policy thing).

(The code reads some state into variables, selects some data into temp tables, and performs some updates and deletes. There are a few loops to perform the deletes in small batches, as not to fill the transaction log.)

If I were writing code in Java I could create some test data and step through the method to watch the data being manipulated. Are there any tools that DB developers use to debug their code in a similar fashion?

Comment: You can use sql management studio, [this article](http://www.dataversity.net/debugging-complex-sql-queries/) may also help you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any details on how your SQL is being processed, eg:

- is your application submitting SQL batches to ASE? perhaps as a looping construct submitting prepared statements? [if so, you'll likely have a better chance of finding a debugger for your application; otherwise, add some print/select statements, perhaps based on a debug variable being set]
- is your application submitting a (large) SQL batch to ASE? [if so, you may be able to use ASE's `sqldbgr` utility to step through your SQL code; you can find  more details about ASE's `sqldbgr` in the [ASE Utility Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570100/doc/html/san1367605051210.html)]